# Sequences $2^n+m$ that tend not to produce primes but it seems that they should

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics

Something about this is surely known. For different $m \in \mathbb Z$ we obtain different sequences $n \to2^n+m$.

Are there some $m$´s for which it is expected that this sequence should give some primes but also some computations in some relatively large ranges were done and not a single prime was found?

What are the examples of some such $m$´s?

Comment: For negative $m$ , $m=-2293$ seems to be a hard case.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what does "it is expected that this sequence should give some primes" mean?

Answer (score 3):

$m=2131$ seems to be a hard case. $n=316$ and $n=496$ show that no small factor is forced. On the other hand, $$2^n+2131$$ is not prime for $1\le n\le 40\ 000$

$m=2\ 491$ gives a prime for $n=3\ 536$ and $4\ 471$ gives a prime for $n=33\ 548$

I can continue the search of hard cases in the case of interest.

"Survivors" upto $n=1\ 000$ in the range $[-10^5,10^5]$ (I omitted the even $m$)

```
[-99959, -99311, -99247, -99067, -98429, -97537, -97225, -97147, -97031, -96877,
 -96629, -96581, -96457, -95497, -95383, -94873, -94109, -94031, -93997, -92947,
 -91961, -91879, -90523, -90241, -89651, -88927, -88477, -88421, -88391, -88327,
 -88091, -88019, -87959, -87007, -86531, -86459, -85747, -85061, -84899, -84491,
 -83381, -83129, -83113, -82889, -82811, -82747, -82559, -82363, -81853, -81701,
 -81329, -81253, -81089, -80197, -79829, -79423, -79417, -79297, -79273, -79049,
 -78733, -77767, -77711, -77471, -77309, -77227, -77099, -76805, -76751, -76003,
 -75989, -74797, -74699, -74587, -74519, -74459, -74309, -74137, -73357, -72251,
 -71399, -70963, -70589, -70571, -70121, -70117, -69869, -69427, -68849, -67349,
 -66937, -66427, -66277, -66217, -66179, -66013, -65167, -65023, -64897, -64331,
 -63779, -63431, -63389, -62983, -62819, -62587, -61541, -60929, -60313, -60089,
 -59399, -58811, -57943, -57817, -57569, -57283, -57163, -56351, -56305, -55807,
 -54847, -54457, -53801, -53741, -53677, -53293, -52859, -52271, -52259, -52201,
 -51733, -50233, -50171, -50107, -49183, -49169, -48959, -48787, -48703, -48071,
 -47107, -46601, -46027, -45493, -44369, -43331, -42581, -42277, -42037, -41533,
 -41497, -41441, -41309, -41017, -40799, -40529, -39509, -39007, -38947, -38879,
 -38563, -38249, -37993, -37867, -36971, -35947, -35921, -35053, -34693, -34573,
 -34169, -33883, -32887, -32471, -31511, -31301, -31063, -30341, -30337, -30283,
 -29101, -28807, -27899, -27493, -26527, -26473, -25859, -25841, -25229, -24733,
 -24217, -23173, -21701, -21673, -21547, -20909, -20707, -19723, -18013, -17609,
 -17159, -15997, -15373, -14827, -14729, -14407, -14347, -14023, -13993, -13903,
 -13603, -12997, -12749, -12517, -12343, -11729, -11173, -10537, -9179, -7709, -
7387, -7057, -6883, -6371, -6269, -6247, -4327, -3821, -3761, -3427, -2977, -229
3, -1871, 2131, 2491, 4471, 5101, 6379, 6887, 7013, 8447, 8543, 9833, 10711, 140
33, 14551, 14573, 14717, 15623, 16519, 17659, 18527, 19081, 19249, 20209, 20273,
 21143, 21661, 22193, 23147, 23221, 23971, 24953, 26213, 26491, 28433, 29333, 29
777, 30197, 31111, 31369, 31951, 32449, 32513, 34429, 35461, 36083, 36721, 37217
, 37967, 38387, 39079, 40291, 40351, 40613, 41453, 41693, 43579, 47269, 48091, 4
8331, 48527, 48859, 48961, 49279, 49577, 50839, 52339, 53119, 53359, 56717, 5708
3, 59071, 60443, 60451, 60947, 60961, 62029, 63691, 64133, 64643, 65033, 65089,
65719, 67607, 69593, 69709, 70321, 72679, 73373, 73583, 75353, 75841, 77041, 777
83, 77899, 78557, 79309, 79463, 80813, 80971, 81091, 81361, 81409, 81919, 84677,
 86329, 86963, 88501, 90053, 91039, 91549, 93203, 93623, 93649, 94639, 94853, 95
297, 95689, 96661, 97621, 97681, 99199, 99413, 99961]
```

$355$ survivors

$10^4$-survivors in the range $[-10^5,10^5]$

```
[-98429, -97147, -96629, -96581, -94109, -92947, -90523, -88421, -88091, -87959,
 -87007, -85061, -84491, -83381, -82363, -81853, -81701, -81329, -81253, -81089,
 -79423, -79417, -79049, -77711, -77227, -75989, -74519, -74137, -70121, -69427,
 -68849, -67349, -65167, -63431, -63389, -59399, -58811, -57943, -57163, -56351,
 -55807, -52859, -52259, -50171, -48959, -48703, -48071, -47107, -37867, -36971,
 -35947, -34693, -31511, -31301, -30337, -30283, -25229, -21673, -20909, -15997,
 -14407, -14347, -14023, -13603, -12749, -12343, -11729, -11173, -6269, -4327, -
3821, -2293, -1871, 2131, 4471, 7013, 8543, 10711, 14033, 14573, 14717, 17659, 1
9081, 19249, 20273, 21661, 22193, 23971, 28433, 34429, 35461, 37967, 39079, 4029
1, 41693, 47269, 48527, 57083, 60443, 60451, 60947, 62029, 63691, 64133, 67607,
75353, 77783, 77899, 78557, 79309, 80971, 81091, 81361, 81919, 91549, 94639, 976
81]
```

$117$ survivors

Comment: The mentioned primes are not yet proven, but pass the BPSW-test.

Comment: $m=2131$ even "survives" the range $[1,80\ 000]$

Answer (score 1):

Erdős had a construcion for the numbers of the form $m\cdot2^n+1$ with fixed $m$; that can be modifided for $2^n+m$. His trick was to cover the integers by aritmetic progressions.

It is easy to verify that $3|2^2-1$, $7|2^3-1$, $5|2^4-1$, $17|2^8-1$, $13|2^{12}-1$ and $241|2^{24}-1$. The set of positive integers can be covered by the arithmetic progressions $\{2k+1\}$, $\{3k+1\}$, $\{4k+2\}$, $\{8k+4\}$, $\{12k+8\}$ and $\{24k\}$.

Hence, let $M=3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot13\cdot17\cdot241=5592405$, and choose a positive integer $m>241$ such that $3|m+2^1$, $7|m+2^1$, $5|m+2^2$, $17|m+2^4$, $13|m+2^8$ and $241|m+2^{0}$. Such an $m$ exists due to the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Then every number of the form $2^n+m$ is divisible by either $3,5,7,13,17$ or $241$.

Comment: Which of the factors covers values of $n$ divisible by $24$?

Comment: Thanks, fixed...

Comment: I do not think that the purpose of this question is to find $m$, for which we know that only finite many (in fact only some small) prime numbers exist, but rather a case , where there is no such covering, so that infinite many primes should exist, but none is known and the smallest is huge. In such a case, we cannot be sure that there actually is such a prime.